# Snowflake - How to get a list of all the users and its assigned roles?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to get a list with all users and its assigned roles.

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want only roles directly granted to users or also roles granted via role-to-role grants?

Comment: @NickW I think it would be better to have all information available, thanks

Comment: Hi - you need to start with these 3 tables and you'll need a recursive query to get all the roles: SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.USERS
SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_USERS
SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES

Comment: To fetch the role-to-role grants(role hierarchy), you can refer to https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-retrieve-the-list-of-roles-and-its-grants-in-the-role-hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a list of users, default roles, and possible roles:

```sql
select name, default_role, default_secondary_role, array_agg(role) roles
from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.USERS a
left join SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_USERS b
on a.name=b.grantee_name
group by 1,2,3
```

To navigate the hierarchy of roles we can use the tip likend by Uma:

- https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-retrieve-the-list-of-roles-and-its-grants-in-the-role-hierarchy